# Javascript Performance improvement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Using Jquery plugin to show a dropdown which looks like this
[image]

Now in the edit page, this drop-down opens with checked checkboxes, I do this with the help of Javascript which is as below

```
var setValues = $("#SelectedFrameworks").val().split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < setValues.length; i++) {
    var selectedElement = $("#frameworksDropDown").find('*[data-id="' + setValues[i] + '"]');
    selectedElement.find("i").addClass("fa-check-square-o").removeClass("fa-square-o");

    SelectParent(selectedElement);           
}

function SelectParent(_element) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $(_element).parent().children().length; i++) {
        if ($(_element).parent().children().eq(i).find("i").attr("class") == "fa select-box fa-check-square-o") {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == $(_element).parent().children().length) {
        $(_element).closest("ul").siblings("i").click();
    }
}
```

I store this value first in the hidden field then use it to Check the checkboxes. (as shown in the code)

Now the problem is, it takes too much time when data is a lot. this causes the page to hang.

I found that operation

```
selectedElement.find("i").addClass("fa-check-square-o").removeClass("fa-square-o");
```

takes too much time. how can I optimize this code to have a better result

**EDIT**

Here is the HTML for this dropdown.[image]

**Note:** this HTML is autogenarated.

Thanks.

Comment: At least, use `each()` instead of looping and re-access the element, I mean this `for (var i = 0; i < $(_element).parent().children().length; i++)` is not good.

Comment: You could probably save a *lot* of computing time by *actually using* `<input type="checkbox">` instead of hacking around with code. You can even use `<label>`s to make the entire "row" clickable without a single line of JavaScript!

Comment: The thing with the Html of this drop-down is, it is Auto-generated I just have one <div> which is field by Javascript of this plugin

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you explain how you check the checkboxes without accessing the DOM within the loop?

Comment: @MatrixTai execution of for is faster than each using each will only gonna increase the time.

Answer (score 3):

So one of the big issues with this code is the amount of times you're calling the DOM. Everytime you do `$(el)` you're calling document.getElementByClassName or id etc. Which is gonna be slow and is unnecessary to make that many calls.

So you can change

```
function SelectParent(_element) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $(_element).parent().children().length; i++) {
        if ($(_element).parent().children().eq(i).find("i").attr("class") == "fa select-box fa-check-square-o") {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == $(_element).parent().children().length) {
        $(_element).closest("ul").siblings("i").click();
    }
}
```

To this, which accesses the DOM once, stores a reference to the element. This will cut down on the amount of DOM calls you make. The biggest advantage to this is of course, speed. I always make a point of naming jquery variables beginning with $ so that it's much easier and quicker to tell what that variable is in the future, or if someone else comes to work on your code.

```
function SelectParent(_element) {
    var count = 0;
    var $element = $(_element);
    var $children =  $element.parent().children();

    for (var i = 0, length = $children.length; i < length; i++) {
        if ($children.eq(i).find("i").attr("class") == "fa select-box fa-check-square-o") {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == $children.length) {
        $element.closest("ul").siblings("i").click();
    }
}
```

Now of course you can refactor the rest to speed it up ;)

Comment: Thanks for the SelectParent() part .good suggestion. but still its taking too much time

Comment: I see the code is automatically generated, is it slow during generation? Also when you're doing .find(i) it has to go through every single element to see if it's an <i> is there any reason you couldn't just add a class to this element and select it with $(.class)?